# Reading csv from URL

Tags: r, url, connection, timeout, read.csv

I am using an API call to download Google Analytics data which are in the csv format (no filename). I am using the following code that allows longer timeouts (url address here is just a nonfunctional example).

```
fy18url <- "https://supermetrics.com/api/q/......lLF_P"
#Set options and open connection to get data
options(timeout = 300)
conn <- url(fy18url)
open(conn, "r")
gadata <- read.csv(conn, check.names=FALSE)
close(conn)
```

However, when I run this code it throws error (first time around) with the following message.

```
> open(conn, "r")
Error in open.connection(conn, "r") : cannot open the 
connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(conn, "r") :
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
> gadata <- read.csv(conn, check.names=FALSE)
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the 
connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
> close(conn)
```

If I run the same code again, it runs fine and I do get all the data. Any idea what causing it?

I was thinking of using a loop to check for data and run it again if no data, but would like to get a simpler solution.
Thanks.

Comment: if you use `httr::GET()` you get a response object with a great deal of metadata along with the content plus you can pass query parameters in a query parameter that makes them much easier to specify and you can also specify explicit timeout values.

Comment: Thank you @hrbrmstr. It is working now after using the httr library and some hints from https://github.com/ropensci/rinat/issues/8.

Comment: if you post an answer others can upvote it and you can also then eventually accept it. it's all kinds of awesome you both asked and self-answered your own question firs time 'round!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the suggestions. Here is what is now working for me.

```
fy18url <- "https://supermetrics.com/api/q/......."
#Set options
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
data <- GET(fy18url, timeout(300))
gadata <- read.csv(textConnection(content(data, as = "text")), check.names=FALSE)
```